# Pandas groupby on list of lists with atleast one element common

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, aggregate

I am analyzing a CSV file with names corresponding to their mobile numbers list.[image: Dataframe]

Now, I wish to group by this dataset over 'phone_number' where at least one of the numbers in the list matches with others.

> For example,** if Dr. ABC has phone_number=['1234','3456','7890'] in
>   one of the samples & Dr. ABC has phone number=['7676','1234','8765']
>   in other sample , these rows should be aggregated together as '1234'
>   is common. Though rows without any match should also be retained

The required output is **list of rx_id** after grouping over phone_number like this.Can this be done using pandas groupby()? or some other trick. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use `explode` and `duplicated`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"doctor_name":["Dr. ABC","Dr. ABC", "Dr. Who","Dr. Strange"],
                   "phone_number":[['1234','3456','7890'],['7676','1234','8765'], np.NaN, ["8697059406"]]})

df = df.explode("phone_number")

s = df["doctor_name"].value_counts()

print (df[df.duplicated("phone_number")|df["doctor_name"].isin(s[s.eq(1)].index)]) #add .groupby("doctor_name").agg(list) if you want them back into a list

   doctor_name phone_number
1      Dr. ABC         1234
2      Dr. Who          NaN
3  Dr. Strange   8697059406
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!! but this code removes Dr.Who & Dr. Strange. Is there any way these two can be retained. I wish to keep rows which don't find a match as well & aggregate those which have a match